# Constituent tree in Python (NLTK)

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, nltk, text-chunking

I have found this code [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/syntax-tree-natural-language-processing/):

```
# Import required libraries 
import nltk 
nltk.download('punkt') 
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger') 
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize, RegexpParser 
   
# Example text 
sample_text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
   
# Find all parts of speech in above sentence 
tagged = pos_tag(word_tokenize(sample_text)) 
   
#Extract all parts of speech from any text 
chunker = RegexpParser(""" 
                       NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}    #To extract Noun Phrases 
                       P: {<IN>}               #To extract Prepositions 
                       V: {<V.*>}              #To extract Verbs 
                       PP: {<P> <NP>}          #To extract Prepostional Phrases 
                       VP: {<V> <NP|PP>*}      #To extarct Verb Phrases 
                       """) 
  
# Print all parts of speech in above sentence 
output = chunker.parse(tagged) 
print("After Extracting\n", output)
```

As I understand, this code defines PP, NP and VP... My doubt is that the syntactic tags are already defined [here](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/docs/LDC95T7/cl93.html). Aren't these composed tags defined in NLTK? Is that the point? Furthermore, in the last row of the chunker `{<V> <NP|PP>*}`, is it using the above-defined `NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}` and `PP: {<P> <NP>}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you found the idea is to use the conventional names for syntactic constituent elements of sentences to create a *chunker* - a parser that breaks down sentences to a desired level of rather coarse-grained pieces. This simple(istic?) approach is used in favour of a full syntactic parse - which would require breaking the utterances down to word-level and labelling each word with appropriate function in the sentence.

The grammar defined in the parameter of `RegexParser` is to be chosen arbitrarily depending on the need (and structure of the utterances it is to apply to). These rules can be recurrent - they correspond to the ones of [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) formal grammar. Your observation is then valid - the last rule for `VP` refers to the previously defined rules.